# Save String from a file and use variable as an argument linux

Tags: linux, command-line, command-substitution

I want to assign a variable to be Strings that I read from the file foo.txt. Then, I want to call a java program with that variable as the argument. However, the argument that keeps getting passed to the program is cat foo.txt. How to I get the program to take in the actual arguments?

```
$ temp='cat foo.txt'
$temp
  > encode test 5
$ echo $temp
  > cat foo.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html), but you're using single quoutes instead of backticks, effectively making it a string.

Corrected (old-style substitution):

```
temp=`cat foo.txt`
```

Better (new-style substitution):

```
temp=$(cat foo.txt)
```

Even better:

```
temp=$(< foo.txt)
```